# the program doesn't recognize onkeyup event- asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, textbox, onkeyup

I have read every single forum including this one about onkeyup event, I tried everything but nothings happens:

I have this JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Count() {
        var i = document.getElementById('txtOr').value.length;
        document.getElementById('lblRem').innerHTML = 20 - i; 
    }
</script>
```

And this is the aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOr" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large"  Height="700px" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"  OnTextChanged="txtOr_TextChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeyup="Count()"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label Text="20" runat="server" ID="lblRem" style="font-size:20px"/>
```

I have tried every method i read online:

- In c# Page_Load method add `txtOr.Attributes.Add("onkeyup","Count()")` [didn't work]
- In Js code do this:  enter code here`

  `function Count() {var i = document.getElementById("<%=txtOr.ClientID%>").value.length; document.getElementById('lblRem').innerHTML = 20 - i; }`

[didn't work]

Anyone who has a solution?

Comment: `document.getElementById('lblRem')` also needs to use the ClientID

Comment: @GuyIncognito I tried, it gives this error in any case: System.Web.HttpException: 'A page can have only one server-side Form tag.'

Comment: That's an unrelated issue.

Comment: @GuyIncognito you meant doing this right?: ...getElementById('<%=lblRem.ClientID%>')

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is painful due to the fact that upper/lower case matters.

This code will work - NOTE VERY carefull the "case" settings of onKeyUp

```
OnKeyup - wrong!
onkeyup - wrong!
Onkeyup - wrong!
ONKEYUP - wrong!

OnKeyUp - correct!!

Note ALSO that you must pass "event" (and again that "event" matters)


        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
            Height="191px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="422px"
            OnKeyUp="mykeypress(event);return false;"
            ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
       <script>

            function mykeypress(e) {

                console.log('key press value = ' + e.keyCode);
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                    alert('you hit the enter key!');
                    // ' get value of text in text box
                    var mytbox = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
                    alert(mytbox.value);

                    // get text box WITHOUT CientIDMode=Static

                    var mytbox2 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
                    alert(mytbox2.value);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

As noted, since the asp.net pre-processor can and will "change" the "ID" values of controls on the page? Then you can use the 2nd approach to get/get a reference to the control (textbox). Or you can set the controls ClientIDMode="Static". I often for jQuery pop up boxes, some div(s) (runat=server - I dont' want the "id" changing, so often I simply use ClientIDMode  = static).

Also, don't forget - OnKeyUp="somefunc(event);" - don't forget the "event" part, else it also not work.

Comment: So in your example 13 is the  keycode for enter? sure, i got it but in my case(my question) should i also pass an event?

Comment: Yes. But "event" in this case is not really a event, but only a "value" that allows you to send the keypress "object" to the function routine. So that "event" is more of a object of a given type. And you use event.KeyCode to get the value of the keypress . (and yes, 13 = enter key 65= "A" etc. good old school ASCII numbers for the most part.